# HTTP Auto Proxy Detection Worker Process high CPU usage

Tags: networking, windows-10, cpu-usage

On a new laptop with Windows 10 Pro Version 1903 I'm experiencing high CPU usage (more than 50%) by usually two processes "HTTP Auto Proxy Detection Worker Process".

[image: Task Manager high CPU usage]

These processes start heavy CPU load whenever network changes (eg. attach/detach network cable or connect to VPN).
When this occurs, Internet communication is no more available.

Killing processes via Task Manager (with administrative privilege) restores Internet access.

These processes are child of svchost and refers to pacjsworker.exe executable.

Any idea on how to solve or further investigate will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a definitive answer but here is a workaround which basically disables the Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Protocol (WPAD):

Put 
`255.255.255.255 wpad.` in the host file `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` 
and reboot. The process should now stop hogging the CPU.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41048991/3515906